# MySQL Procedure if else to detect same id and insert new student

Tags: mysql

```
mysql>delimiter //
mysql>create procedure add_student
(
in student_id decimal(10),
in name varchar(20),
in course varchar(10),
in address varchar(10),
in bday varchar(15),
in gender varchar(10))
begin
if exists(select *from student_id where student_id=student_id)
select'student alredy exist'
else
select'New student added'
insert into student values(student_id,name,course,address,bday,gender)
endif
end; 
//
```

plzzz help

Comment: You aren't much of a sweet talker this morning are ya

Comment: What help do you need? not clear with your question.

Comment: sorry sir,  im having a problem making a procedure that can read if the student_id i entered is already in use or exists in my table ,, if not the it will insert in my student table      @C4u

Answer (score 0):

**According your comment below your question (should be edited):**

Set up a unique key on your `student_id` (if not done already) and use `INSERT IGNORE`.

**Quote from the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)**

> If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors that occur while executing the INSERT statement are ignored. For example, without IGNORE, a row that duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With IGNORE, the row is discarded and no error occurs. Ignored errors may generate warnings instead, although duplicate-key errors do not.

Means if you insert a new row that already exists, it will be skipped. This is your `if -> else` part.